# Website shows textbox in debugger but not when hosted w/ISS ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, textbox

I've been tracking to tackle this issue and narrowed it down, but first a little description:
I have a website that a client would fill out, some basic text boxes, bullets, and dropdowns. They click submit and the information they submitted (nothing sensitive) is Response.Redirect(ed) to another page which has text boxes that are populated by the information included in the redirect. This page also prints itself for the client to sign.

The issue started when I added one more field to the redirect page so that it appears as well when printed. It simply does not appear on the page or the print out and I cross-checked the properties with all the other textboxes and everything is the same. Now, I did narrow it down in that the new textbox does appear when using the built in debugger for MS Visual Web Dev 2010 Express but it does not appear when I host the website on the local IIS server. From here it seems to be obvious that the issue is a setting on the IIS service.

To the question: What setting in IIS would cause a newly added textbox to not appear under the circumstances mentioned? Also, am I approaching this website as a whole in a round-a-bout way i.e. instead of redirecting to another website the populates data, prints itself, and redirects back to the host page is there an "internal" form I can have the data sent to and print from there?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I setup the ISS server/website under and an administrator account with the website being under a folder on the desktop. I overlooked this fact and copy/pasted the website folder to the desktop of a different non-administrator account and so naturally none of the changes were actually showing because IIS wasn't even pointing to that website folder of the non-admin account. Once I dumped the modified files under the proper folder under the admin account they finally appeared in production.